# What is the meaning of following driver_options params?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, pdo

I'm working on some project in my company, and client asked me to change few things in database. Project was not done by us. After few hours of work I saw these config lines:

```
resources.db.adapter                     = "PDO_MYSQL"
resources.db.params.host                 = "localhost"
resources.db.params.dbname               = "db"
resources.db.params.username             = "db-user"
resources.db.params.password             = "db-password"
resources.db.params.charset              = "utf8"
resources.db.params.driver_options.1006  = true
resources.db.params.driver_options.1000  = true
```

Can anyone tell me what exactly these driver options mean? I was googling around for some time and couldn't find any other answer but this: these are driver specific options...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
MYSQL_ATTR_DIRECT_QUERY = 1006
MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY = 1000
```

http://www.wolfcms.org/phpdoc/latest/Framework/Record.html

For info on those options: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php